# php - internal server error when trying to grab fields from decoded json

Tags: php

I made the following JSON to handle some values:

```
    {
        "maxpoints": "10",
        "text": "Write a function that...",
        "func": "add",
        "constraints": ["While", "If"],
        "testcases":[
            {
            "output": "100",
            "input": ["10", "30", "60"]
            },
            {
            "output": "100",
            "input": ["10", "30", "60"]
            },
            {
            "output": "100",
            "input": ["10", "30", "60"]
            },
            {
            "output": "100",
            "input": ["10", "30", "60"]
            },
            {
            "output": "100",
            "input": ["10", "30", "60"]
            }
        ]
}
```

And I used json_encode to convert it to a string, to hardcode it in a variable in PHP and then grab the fields using the code below:

```
$question = json_decode("    {\n    \t\"maxpoints\": \"10\",\n    \t\"text\": \"Write a function that...\",\n    \t\"func\": \"add\",\n    \t\"constraints\": [\"While\", \"If\"],\n    \t\"testcases\":[\n    \t\t{\n    \t\t\"output\": \"100\",\n        \t\"input\": [\"10\", \"30\", \"60\"]\n    \t\t},\n    \t\t{\n    \t\t\"output\": \"100\",\n        \t\"input\": [\"10\", \"30\", \"60\"]\n    \t\t},\n    \t\t{\n    \t\t\"output\": \"100\",\n        \t\"input\": [\"10\", \"30\", \"60\"]\n    \t\t},\n    \t\t{\n    \t\t\"output\": \"100\",\n        \t\"input\": [\"10\", \"30\", \"60\"]\n    \t\t},\n    \t\t{\n    \t\t\"output\": \"100\",\n        \t\"input\": [\"10\", \"30\", \"60\"]\n    \t\t}\n    \t]\n}");
    $maxpoints = $question["maxpoints"];
    $text = $question["text"];
    $func = $question["func"];
    $constraints = $question["constraints"];
    $testcases = $question["testcases"];
```

However, I have narrowed down my error to be in these 6 lines, but can't seem to find what I did wrong no matter how hard I look. I know for a fact that my link to my php script is fine, because I used several print statements to see where the flow stopped.

This is the code I use to test this script in my chrome console:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('request_type', 'store_question');
fetch("back.php", {method: 'POST', body: formData})
.then((resp) => console.log(resp.text()));
```

This is the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/LntLar see the issue there?

Comment: maxpoints is a list, so I can't get its value by using it as a key search on $question?

Comment: If this question ever gains clarity, please ping me and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because `json_decode` converts the string into object by default and you trying yo access it as an associative array.

You have set the second parameter to `true` to make it an associative array

```
json_decode ( $json, true )
```

Try this:

```
$question = json_decode("    {\n    \t\"maxpoints\": \"10\",\n    \t\"text\": \"Write a function that...\",\n    \t\"func\": \"add\",\n    \t\"constraints\": [\"While\", \"If\"],\n    \t\"testcases\":[\n    \t\t{\n    \t\t\"output\": \"100\",\n        \t\"input\": [\"10\", \"30\", \"60\"]\n    \t\t},\n    \t\t{\n    \t\t\"output\": \"100\",\n        \t\"input\": [\"10\", \"30\", \"60\"]\n    \t\t},\n    \t\t{\n    \t\t\"output\": \"100\",\n        \t\"input\": [\"10\", \"30\", \"60\"]\n    \t\t},\n    \t\t{\n    \t\t\"output\": \"100\",\n        \t\"input\": [\"10\", \"30\", \"60\"]\n    \t\t},\n    \t\t{\n    \t\t\"output\": \"100\",\n        \t\"input\": [\"10\", \"30\", \"60\"]\n    \t\t}\n    \t]\n}" , true );
$maxpoints = $question["maxpoints"];
$text = $question["text"];
$func = $question["func"];
$constraints = $question["constraints"];
$testcases = $question["testcases"];
```

Doc: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)